# How to make responsive gallery layout in bootstrap?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I made gallery, but once i resize the window, images start to stack. How can I make the layout stay the same for every screen size?

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="images/tepihg1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Tepih1"> <img src="images/tepihg1.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a>
        <a href="images/tepihg2.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Tepih2"> <img src="images/tepihg2.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a>
        <a href="images/tepihg3.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Tepih3"> <img src="images/tepihg3.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.gallery {
    margin: 30px 0 50px;

}
.gallery img {
    max-width: 200px; 
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 5px;
}

.gallery img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Please, use the `{}` button to insert your code properly. Please, check the Code of Conduct [https://stackoverflow.com/conduct], and never post code as an image as it makes hard to understand it.

Comment: I did but I constantly get message that my code isn't properly formatted as code. I clicked on { } button and left 4 spaces and tried CTRL+K, but I get same message again and again, and got frustrated.

Comment: Just paste your code as a normal text, then you can select all your code and click on `{}`. This is the best way to insert a block of code.

Comment: Thank you man, finally, I thought I need to press { } first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the `.gallery img` CSS. If you are going to show only 3 images. The max-width must be 33.33% minus the padding. Check this snippet.

```html
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="gallery">
        <a href="images/tepihg1.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Tepih1"> <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a>
        <a href="images/tepihg2.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Tepih2"> <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a>
        <a href="images/tepihg3.jpg" data-lightbox="mygallery" data-title="Tepih3"> <img src="https://wallpaperbrowse.com/media/images/3848765-wallpaper-images-download.jpg" class="img-fluid"> </a>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
.gallery {
    margin: 30px 0 50px;

}
.gallery img {
    max-width: calc(33.3333% - 20px);
    object-fit: cover;
    padding: 5px;
}

.gallery img:hover{
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Now just images are different sizes, any help with that?

Comment: And if I want to add more pictures, how does the max-width change?

Comment: Maybe you could try a image slider. Like this: https://www.jssor.com/demos/image-gallery.slider